# sending data from Javascript to remote php

Tags: php, javascript

I am modifying a script to make up a firefox extension for my website. The original script ( chrome extension) stores data into a local websql database. I want it rather to send the three variable to a php file using this format
http://mysite.com/receiver.php?id=href&&title=hostname&&article=article&&article=title

The part of Js that is normally sending the data is the following

```
                // post credentials to background
                chrome.extension.sendRequest({
                    action: 'queryDatabase',
                    crud: 'create',
                    record: [
                        window.location.href,
                        window.location.hostname,
                        title,
                        article
                    ]
                });
```

I would be glad if any one can lead me through the modification of this code

Comment: either use a jQuery ajax call [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/] or if you don't care about a response use the URL as formatted to load an image (works best if the PHP script response is a 1x1px gif

Comment: Actually I don't expect any answer. Can you show me an example of the url loading an image ? or just tell me where i can find it

Comment: added an alternate answer - the image one. Both methods are good, depending on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's ajax() method to accomplish this:

```
// post credentials to http://mysite.com/receiver.php
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "http://mysite.com/receiver.php",
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    id: "href",
    title: "hostname",
    article: "article"
  }
}).success(function ( data ) {
  alert("completed successfully");
}).error(function ( data ) {
  alert("there was an error");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I've tried it but it seems that something is wrong with my php file

Answer (score 0):

example of the image/PHP solution. The jQuery Ajax solution listed is good if you need to know what was returned (I use it on things like http://jsErrLog.appspot.com and it's a great solution), the image is good if you just want to throw something over the fence and move on. Both as non-blocking

in the HTML page the Javascript would need to trigger a call that requests an image:

```
<script>
    databaseImage = new Image(); 
    databaseImage.src = "http://mysite.com/receiver.php?id=href&&title=hostname&&article=article&&article=title";
</script>
```

and the PHP page that it calls would, after storing the data, would need to return an image (cleaner than sending back something inappropriate) -

```
<? 
    $im = file_get_contents('{path to your 1px .gif}'); 
    header('content-type: image/gif'); 
    echo $im; 
?>
```

Comment: Shall the php file be like this ?

Comment: <?php
         $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","log");
         // Check connection
         if (mysqli_connect_errno())
           {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
         $domain = $_GET["href"] ;
         $title = $_GET["title"] ;
        $article = $_GET["article"] ;
   
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO articles (domain, title, article) VALUES ('$domain', '$title', '$article')");

    mysqli_close($con);

    $im = file_get_contents('{path to your 1px .gif}'); 
    header('content-type: image/gif'); 
    echo $im; 
    ?>

Comment: that looks okay, I don't have a PHP environment to hand to confirm but should be quick and easy to test (you can just hit the URL for that file and see if you get an image back...)

Comment: it gets the image buck but it stores nothing in the database

Comment: I'd open a separate Q and see if there's a PHPer who can help out with the DB insert quickly (I can't get to a machine until tonight) ... but hopefully one of the two answers your question about how to call it

Comment: no worries. if one or more of the answer has been helpful up-votes are good to guide other users reviewing the question later on